# Jitter Plot ggplot overlay bar graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using a package that gives a swarm plot (See below), However, I want to color each row differently so I am trying to use ggplot and geom_jitter to do so instead.

I have managed to get something close to what I want however I am still struggling to do the following:

1. non-significant Pvalues should be in light grey to help show which ones are significant similar to the swarm plot.
2. overlay a bargraph that shows the mean logFC for the significant points only.

[image: Swarm Plot]
[image: My attempt]

The code I am using is:

```
da_results$P = da_results$SpatialFDR
da_results$P = 1-da_results$P
da_results$P[da_results$P < 0.90] = 0
ggplot(da_results, aes(x=ident, y=logFC,color = ident))+
  geom_point(aes(alpha =     da_results$P),position=position_jitter(height=.75, width=.25))+
  geom_bar(stat = "summary",alpha=0.5) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c('#e6194b', '#3cb44b', '#ffe119', '#4363d8', '#f58231', '#911eb4', '#46f0f0', '#f032e6', '#bcf60c', '#fabebe', '#008080', '#e6beff', '#9a6324', '#800000', '#aaffc3', '#808000', '#ffd8b1', '#000075', '#808080', '#000000',"orange","#FF6865"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your data, so I'll demonstrate with some fake data (far below).

Some things to get this to work:

- I'll plot the points twice, once for "not significant" (gray, I'll use `lim <- 1` as that for here), and once for "significant" (using the colors);
- `scale_*_manual(.)` is much safer using named colors, otherwise the order of factors can change what is available. I tend to do this by predefining the frame with known factors, and whichever aesthetics I will be controlling (such as `color=`, `fill=`, `size=`, `shape=`, etc). Once the frame is defined, I just use `setNames(., .)` to provide a *named vector*, so that assigning a color "xyz" to factor "abc" is unambiguous. It's okay to have named elements in the `scale_*_manual(.)` that are not present in the data.

```r
library(dplyr)
means <- summarize(dat, .by = name, mu = mean(value))
my_aes <- tribble(
  ~ name, ~ color
, "Aa", "#e6194b"
, "Bb", "#3cb44b"
, "Cc", "#ffe119")

lim <- 1 # inside of which the dots will be gray
ggplot(dat, aes(value, name)) +
  geom_jitter(aes(alpha = pmin(1, abs(value))), data = ~ filter(., abs(value) < lim), color = "gray") +
  geom_jitter(aes(color = name), data = ~ filter(., abs(value) >= lim)) +
  geom_col(aes(x = mu, color = name, fill = name), data = means, alpha = 0.2) +
  scale_color_manual( values = setNames(my_aes$color, my_aes$name) ) +
  theme(
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_blank(),
    axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")
  ) +
  guides(alpha = "none")
```

(I use `tribble` here only to clearly show the observations ... normal `data.frame` works just as well. Also, I used `filter` since I'm using `dplyr` in the `means` determination, but if needed those can both be translated to base R.)

[image: ggplot with insignificant points colored gray, significant points colored by the "name" variable, and boxes added to stretch out to each name's mean]

---

Data

```r
set.seed(42)
dat <- data.frame(
  Aa = rnorm(1000, 1, 1),
  Bb = rnorm(1000, 0.5, 2),
  Cc = rnorm(1000, -1, 1)
) |>
  pivot_longer(cols = everything())

head(dat)
# # A tibble: 6 × 2
#   name   value
#   <chr>  <dbl>
# 1 Aa     2.37 
# 2 Bb     5.15 
# 3 Cc    -0.749
# 4 Aa     0.435
# 5 Bb     1.55 
# 6 Cc    -1.28
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked well except for two things: 1) How can I make the bars the same color just lighters, right now they are gray. I tried using "fill" but it threw an error and 2) How can I use alpha for the geom_point, I want them to be darkers for more significant p-values (a third variable).

Comment: See my edit @user23595218. Namely, adding `geom_col(.., alpha=0.2)` is for your (1), and for (2) we can add `aes(alpha=..)` to the first `geom_jitter`, then suppress then alpha legend with `guides(alpha="none")`.

Comment: I used the simple `pmin(1, abs(value))`, you can use something different to perhaps exaggerate the level of alpha you need (power transforms, etc).

Comment: Thank you! I will try a power transform maybe to exaggerate the difference. However when I use fill=ident in geom_col it is applying a different color than the border (color = ident).

Comment: You likely need to add `scale_fill_manual(values = setNames(my_aes$color, my_aes$name))` or similar